# textContent as a number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the content of a  in html, it is a number. I want to have it in javascript so I can do calculations with it. The only problem is that it is returned as string. How can I get the content as a number?

Comment: **...** convert it to a number.

Comment: you can use `Number` Object like  `Number("5")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to parse it as either an int or a float (depending on what this number represents).

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("addBtn");
btn.addEventListener("click",function(){
    var numberTxt = document.getElementById("number").value;
    var number = parseInt(numberTxt,10);
     console.log(number+1);
});
```

```html
<label for="number">Number:</label>
<input type="text" id="number"/>
<input type="button" value="add 1 to number" id="addBtn"/>
```

For a thorough explanation about `parseInt` please have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt). Furthermore, regarding the `parseFloat`, please have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat). Reading both the references and thinking about what you want to do, you would pick either `parseFloat` or `parseInt` and you will make it.